# Where to put time expressions in passive sentences?

Tags: passive-voice

I want to know where to put time expressions in passive sentences?
Which sentence is correct?

> The room is cleaned every week by Joe.

or

> The room is cleaned by Joe every week.

Comment: What makes you think either one of those is incorrect? Please explain - they each look fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

They are both fine, though they have slightly different meanings. A subtle difference of nuance.

> The room is cleaned every week by Joe

The room is cleaned every week, and it is Joe that does it.

> The room is cleaned by Joe every week

Joe cleans it every week, but someone else might clean it at other times as well.

Comment: Are you sure?  I can look at the first one of your examples and draw the opposite conclusion.  Maybe I’m an outlier, but I think it’s pretty ambiguous.

Comment: @whiskeychief It could easily be dialectal.